# Move SWF shape points with as3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shapes, points, morphing

I have SWF vector shape, how to get access to control points of this shape? I want to move some points of this shape with as3 code. SWF created with flash professional CS5, code in flash develop.

Other way to create some Sprites in CS5, and move them with as3, but how to tie them with shape control points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employ `readGraphicsdata()` to read the GraphicsPath of your shape, it contains commands and control/anchor points. You can then parse that vector to find out the point you want to alter, then you change it, then you feed the path back into your shape via `graphics.clear(); graphics.drawPath(path);`, or use `drawGraphicsData()` instead to draw the complete set of graphics shape.

[The manual on readGraphicsData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData%28%29)

[The manual on GraphicsPath class format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsPath.html)

Comment: Thanks! Two things i problems to notice. readGraphicsData() is a new method implemented for Flash Player 11.6 or higher. If compilation target player is lower version, you will not see this method. This method can be called with any Graphics class object, as Sprite MovieClip and Shape.

Comment: Yep, pitiful in fact. You could `drawPath()` way earlier but you couldn't retrieve said path from a given `Graphics`. So the proper solution was to export the shape as a vector of commands and data, and then use its altered copy to draw code-altered shapes.